# Xwiki - ASfter moving page breadcrumb still shows the (pre-move) breadcrumb

Tags: wiki, xwiki

I’m on tomcat9 XWiki Debian 14.9 (22.04)
After moving a folder page, I noticed that the breadcrumb still shows the (pre-move) breadcrumb.

I've tried looking at the json messages which show the propper (post-move) location as page id with the right parent/children relations.

1. Is there any way to force the updating of a breadcrumb?
2. Any ideas/suggestions how to adress/bugfix this issue? i.e. where is the breadcrumb is stored (I could change it manually then)

Comment: The breadcrumb shows the location from which the page has been moved, which is the original location (even though the page is no longer there). I know of no good way to update this. Usually when I want to go to the new page after the move, I click on the breadcrumb showing the location of the moved page (on the right side for wide browser windows, on the bottom for smaller resolutions) to go to the page at the new location.

Answer (score 0):

created a new page and copied the contents of the old one to solve.